# What to do with questions where the author inserted gibberish to bypass the minimum length check?

Tags: discussion, questions, flags

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44680085/mips-i-dont-know-why-code-is-not-running-help-me-please) question while going through the triage review queue. The question body was quite large, however almost all of it was code. The question itself was a couple of sentences long. What grabbed my attention was the following phrase written right underneath (which as of this edit is no longer there):

> Stackflow wants me to writte more text but that all information you need i think. So bla bla bla bla bla. Sry for the Bla's.

I had a good giggle, but once that faded I realized I had no idea what to do with the review. As a proud citizen of SO I couldn't mark it as okay, so I downvoted and skipped it.

So what is meta's stance on this. Should questions like this be flagged? If so, which flag should be used?

Comment: I this particular example I would mark it as unsalvageable.  The OP should explain how it does not work which would most likely have made the minimum character count needed.

Comment: I would have already marked it as unsalvageable before I even got to that part when I noticed it started with "So..." (I'm kidding! I actually never would have been in the triage review queue to begin with.)

Comment: Kind of ironic they didn't spell out "Sorry"...

Comment: @Don'tPanic Well when you're under 2k rep you still have to do something with your time.

Comment: I certainly didn't mean to sound like I was belittling your contribution. I hope it didn't come off that way. I really appreciate that people do triage review. I need to get back into doing more reviews myself.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Nah mate just messing around. Give your own username a read from time to time :P

Comment: Oh good. I prefer to only offend people intentionally.

Comment: "I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we need more information than that. Now shut up and explain the difference between what your code should do and what it's doing right now."

Comment: The Meta-Effect is strong with this one.

Answer (score 31):

Yes, you can flag questions like these as 'Unclear what you're asking' or as off-topic:

> Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and the *shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Specifically, the *specific problem or error* is missing. 'Not working' is not specific enough.

That means you should choose <kbd>Unsalvageable</kbd> in Triage. Also, [when in doubt, use <kbd>Skip</kbd>](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252195/there-is-no-shame-in-using-skip) and post your doubts on Meta :)

Comment: The OP didn't even ask why the code is "not working", he asked why the code is "nor wroking".

Answer (score 16):

That question perfectly fits the off-topic close reason (emphasis mine):

> Questions seeking debugging help **("why isn't this code working?")** must
>   include the desired behavior, a **specific problem or error** and the
>   shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.
>   Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other
>   readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable
>   example.

So picking unsalvageable with this reason would have been the right thing to do in Triage.

Comment: That may fit the text of the off-topic reason, but that doesn't mean it's off-topic. "Unclear" is a better close reason.

Comment: @JasonS I mean I agree that you could also say "unclear what you're asking" but I can't really follow your first sentence. The question as it currently stands is by definition off-topic.

Comment: According to the text of the off-topic reason, yes, it is, *by definition*, off-topic. I don't agree with it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to disagree with the other answers and say that you should downvote, vote to close, *and* flag this as rude/abusive. (See also [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354307/is-it-rude-abusive-to-include-junk-text-to-bypass-the-minimum-texts-requirements)).

Granted, posts that do this will likely be closable as either unclear or insufficient information to debug, so the other answers are correct in that regard. The minimum text requirements are there for a reason, and if they didn't meet it they're probably not describing their problem well enough. So it's perfectly valid to vote to close and downvote.

However, the fact that this entails a deliberate, knowing violation of site rules makes this even worse than just posting an unclear question, so it should be flagged as rude/abusive.

Answer (score 1):

I've added a comment to this question, but I didn't see there was a Meta post.

So here is what I've done, and what I would suggest to do in this case:

- Explain the OP why "*Stackflow wants me to writte more text but that all information you need i think. So bla bla bla bla bla. Sry for the Bla's.*" does not fit our rules, and how the question could be improved.
- Edit the question to remove this content. It's a professional site.
- Vote to close as off-topic

Here is the comment I put:

> Just to answer the *"Stackflow wants me to writte more text but that
>   all information you need i think. So bla bla bla bla bla. Sry for the
>   Bla's."* part: Could you explain what is not working? What is the
>   unexpected/expected result?

Answer (score -39):

> What to do with questions where the author inserted gibberish to bypass the minimum length check?

IMHO this is a symptom that the minimum length should be smaller.

Comment: So, 20 words, 5 of which are completely useless, is enough to ask a quality question?

Comment: I have yet to see a question where this minimum length was hit and the question was **not** missing some essential information (in this example: an actual problem description beyond "nor wroking [sic]"). The problem is the question author, who instead of thinking "oh, let me write a more detailed description" thought "hey, what a stupid error. I am smarter than this. I cannot possibly do anything wrong. I am special. The rules don't apply to me. Let's just work around them".

Comment: @NathanOliver What are the 5 useless words? "Thanks in advance for helping"?

Comment: @stybl *I'm new to MIPS coding* adds nothing to the actual question.

Comment: @NathanOliver Aah I see. I thought you meant in general.

Comment: How about "How can I split a String using a regex?" That's 9 words. A reasonable question (especially in languages that are not as well-documented as, say, Python or Javascript)

Comment: "The rules don't apply to me. Let's just work around them" -- No, the rules are draconian and inflexible so I'll play the game in my own subversive way.

Comment: @JasonS Split a string into what? What is the expected output? Can you give a sample input and output? If someone answers this question as it is OP is most likely to come up with special requests later like "hey thanks for answering but I want to exclude special characters from the string. but not ! and..."

Comment: How about "Why is casting malloc's return discouraged?"