# Is there a minimum length to consider a question as 'a good one'?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions, question-quality

I stumbled upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73316329/replay-request-or-copy-request-as-curl-in-flutter-devtools)

Is there a minimum length to consider a question 'a good one'? This question seems... fairly self explanatory as it is, but my first reaction was to think of it as an automatic 'needs improvement' (I didn't flag though).

Should we flag these questions or try to promote larger questions, or should we just let them be if they are good enough? Which leads me to the next question. Is it even possible to explain a good question in just a line or two, here in SE/SO?

Comment: That all depends on how much of a wizard the author is with words. I would say most people need to explain themselves thoroughly. But some people can tell a whole story in just one or two well-crafted sentences.

Comment: If anything I think we should encourage shorter questions over longer ones.

Comment: @Dharman That would be true in a site where you are not shooting yourself in the foot if the first version of your question is not immediately perfect. But given that this is Stack Overflow... it is probably better to provide a little too much info. There are still human beings behind the questions and they may not be very good at reasoning what information is relevant. Besides that, English may not be their first or even second language.

Comment: Length per se is irrelevant to goodness.

Comment: Such short questions are likely to be duplicates of the existing [22,888,144 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions). Or otherwise close worthy.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10504/enforcing-a-question-minimum-character-length

Comment: High quality questions are rarely those that only fulfill the bare minimum.

Comment: I tried to answer with "No." I got an error message "Body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 3." I think this i a good example on how restrictions can make things worse sometimes.

Comment: @Braiam So the minimum for high quality questions should be 37 pieces of flair?

Comment: @DrewReese Show me a high quality question that has only 30 characters.

Comment: Lengthening questions **often makes them worse**. Especially in cases where OP feels compelled to contribute a broken, off-track attempt at solving the problem, rather than simply explaining a thought process and indicating where the sticking point is.

Comment: Question to the point is always good, nut at the same time question with additional info is not appriciated

Comment: Note: high quality is better. But good quality is good enough. A short question *might* fall in the good quality category. But probably not.

Comment: I personally don't think it is even easy to distinguish a high quality question from a good quality one since some subjective factors might have to be taken into account.

Comment: @S.Dre well that is where the quality votes should come in.

Comment: [37 pieces of flair reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F7SNEdjftno&t=29). [Another scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ChQK8j6so8). [A less well-known scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6NjLTnI9uGM&t=1m20s).

Comment: Nobody going with the quote that Mark Twain did not say, “I would have made this letter shorter if I had more time”?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel It easier to a rough diamond remove its roughness, than to fill in material that isn't there. Minimal is only for code, but if you are unable to do so, I prefer them to keep it as long as they believe they should.

Comment: @SaschaDoerdelmann Agreed, and it seems odd that the minimum length of an answer should be exactly the same as the minimum length of a question. I can't concoct a good question in only 30 characters, but (for certain forms of question) it seems entirely possible to provide a complete answer in less than 30 characters.

Comment: @skomisa "complete" != "good" wtr answers, and questions are supposed to foster answers that explain why or how. I don't think other than "because they said so" any answer explaining why/how would be less than 30 characters.

Comment: Related: [What to do with questions where the author inserted gibberish to bypass the minimum length check?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/351075/1595451)

Answer (score 64):

Is the question clear, and does it contain enough information to be answered? If so, it's fine—maybe even "good".

There is a minimum length enforced by the system. I believe it's currently set to 30 characters. Beyond this absolute minimum, we feel that the quality of a question should be evaluated on a case-by-case basis.

Under no circumstances should questions be flagged because they are "too short". You may, depending on your own subjective opinions about the quality of the question, choose to downvote it. But length *alone* is never a flag reason.

Comment: Thanks Cody. I was more or less inclined to think the same. I would not flag it by length alone, but maybe if the shortness of it affects the overall quality because it does not explain everything as it should. But again, as you say, a short question might be just good enough in some cases.

Comment: I think it will surprise no one to hear that I generally believe that length is correlated with quality. But still, there are exceptions.

Comment: Yes. I would argue that in most cases, length can be very helpful in making a good question. I guess that, at the end, size always mattered.

Comment: I'll test that now with _"Is never a subtype of null?"_  -> _"Body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 27"_;)

Comment: That's not an adequate question, @iLuvLogix; the rejection is valid. In particular, you don't give enough context for people to figure out what you're asking about. You would *at least* need to say something like, "In language X, is...".

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks for clarifying but I was already aware of that. I just wanted to test the 30 chars threshold - that's it..

Comment: Note that the Low Quality Answers Review queue has the text _This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its **length** and **content**._ which may be a bit confusing but that is for answers (although there could be good short answers as well)...

Answer (score 29):

Is the question clear and focused?  If so, we shouldn't encourage people to write more text that everyone who comes across it will have to read.

Comment: Yes, I did the same short-post joke.  But I think it gets my point across... it contains everything needed to understand it.

Comment: Flagged as plagiarism. And irony.

Comment: I hope this doesn't become twitter. Thanks for the input guys.

Comment: @CodyGray Where is the irony flag? I need it. We all need it.

Comment: @RyanM Joke? What joke? Where's my pun, I was promised a pun.

Comment: Have you ever tried to write a pun, @philipxy? It's quite a difficult pun-dertaking! (Although the creation of a good pun is its own reword.) I know our puns have groan on you, but making these kinds of demands is just pun-reasonable. I tried writing ten different puns hoping one would get a laugh, but no pun in ten did.

Comment: @CodyGray [A few meta.se comments ago.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375081/new-post-summary-designs-on-site-home-pages-and-greatest-hits-now-everywhere-el/376201#comment1269957_376201)

Answer (score 17):

We already have a flag for a question that needs more detail. Adding a way to flag questions for being too short (on the assumption that shorter questions need more detail) is really just duplicating the existing flag for a second-order complaint.

If it has enough detail, it's long enough. If it doesn't have enough detail, the problem isn't the *length*.

Comment: I prefer more that OP provides as many details as possible, and remove it post-facto rather than having no/little details. In some cases irrelevant details can help towards directing OP to provide the relevant ones.

Comment: @Braiam That's true, but doesn't change the fact that a question that _does_ have enough detail is long enough. You're addressing something different: the very high chance that a poster, who obviously already doesn't understand something, will be able to know exactly _which_ details are sufficient,

Answer (score 5):

Questions need to have enough details for people to reasonably be able to identify what the OP is confused about; otherwise, they may waste time answering something that doesn't really address the OP's main confusion. For example, a few years ago I saw a zero-effort homework dump; after pressing the OP for more details about what they were *actually* confused about, they added a MRE. It turns out they already had (mostly) working code; the only thing that they were confused about is that they thought that calling Java's `Math.abs` function on an each element of an array would update the array "in place" (which it doesn't). That particular confusion is easy to address in an answer; however, if I hadn't pressed for more details, I wouldn't have known to address that particular point, and the answer would've been far less useful.

That being said, a question is "long enough" when it has enough details for people to be able to be sure that they're addressing the OP's actual problem.

Answer (score 4):

Provided the question is clear and contains all necessary information I consider brevity is a positive rather than a negative.

Comment: "If the question is clear and self-contained, short is good."

Comment: @KarlKnechtel "shortness" shouldn't be a qualifier. It should contain exactly as much as it should.

Comment: @Braiam it was simply a joke (rephrasing the answer more concisely).

Answer (score 3):

No

---

Post minimal length validation is done automatically to help reduce spammy posts and prevent the reviewing queues to be cluttered with very likely bad posts. It should not be used by SO members as a reviewing / voting shortcut.

If you find many bad questions having in common being barely above the minimal length enforced automatically, it might be good to discuss the appropriate minimal length, I think, but when occasionally finding shorts questions, rather to focus on the question length ask yourself if the question is clear and complete, if it's original (it have not been asked before on SO), if it might be helpful for others and if it might get 'good SO answers'.

By the way, sometimes I find it very helpful to look at the comments and answers to decide if a question is 'good'.

Answer (score -1):

Shortness is usually an indications of meh-ness. It rarely makes a good through provoking question. Note that the [how to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) doesn't refer to length other than how to create an MCVE and that applies to code, something that we already established that when in doubt prefer a complete and verifiable example over a minimal one. There's a minimum length to post a question at all, and even that is very short. A couple of sentences is enough to pass that criteria, but we still should prefer people to post more and we remove it, than to post less and we have to ask for it. After all, the perfect question doesn't exist.